# Controller not getting selected nor returning second view Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, controller

i have a dropdown list in witch the user select soemthing and then it should send the selected option to my controller and save it on a viewbag then my controller returns a new view, in the new view my table body should use the viewbag item for a statement in my model but for some reason when the user selects the option nothing happens.. the controller doesnt trigger the new view or pass the selected option
This is my controller

```html
namespace Arpon.Web.Brain.Pos.Controllers
{
    public class HomePosController : BaseController
    {
        //
        // GET: /HomePos/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var db = new ArponClientPosContext();

            return View("~/Views/HomePos/Index.cshtml", db.Pos.ToList());
           
        }

        public ActionResult SimpleInterest(String pdvlist)
        {
            var db = new ArponClientPosContext();
            SimpleInterestModel model = new SimpleInterestModel();

            ViewBag.key1 = "0";
                ViewBag.key1 = pdvlist;
                return View("~/Views/HomePos/IndexF.cshtml", db.Pos.ToList());
        }

    }
}
```

And also my View:

```html
@using Arpon.Web.Loader.Utils.Helpers;
@model ICollection<Arpon.Web.Brain.Pos.Models.Pos>
@ViewBag.key1
<script>
    onDocExtendedLoad(
    function run() {

        var PdvId = document.getElementById("pdvlist").value;
            $('select[name=pdvlist]').change(function () { alert($(this).val()); });
    }
    );
</script>


<div class="page-title">
    <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
    <h3>POS</h3>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 sortable">
                <div class="grid simple vertical green">
                    <div class="grid-title no-border">
                        <h4>@this.FP("Punto de Venta")</h4>
                        <div class="tools">
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse"></a>
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="reload"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-body no-border">
                        <div class="p-l-20 p-r-20 p-b-10 p-t-10 b-b b-grey">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5 class="bold pull-left m-r-5">@this.FP("lbl.loader.date")</h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <div class="input-append success no-padding">
                                                <div id="reportrange" class="pull-right div-daterangepicker">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg"></i>
                                                    <span>@date.ToString("d MMMM, yyyy") - @date.ToString("d MMMM, yyyy")</span> <b class="caret"></b>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5 class="bold pull-left m-r-5">@this.FP("Restaurante")</h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <div class="input-append success no-padding">
                                                <select class="ctl-source">
                                                    <option value="">Todos</option>
                                                    <option value="DE">Desayuno</option>
                                                    <option value="CO">Comida</option>
                                                    <option value="CE">Cena</option>
                                              
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5 class="bold pull-left m-r-5">@this.FP("PDV")</h5>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <div class="input-append success no-padding">
                                                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                                                {
                                                    <select id="pdvlist" name="pdvlist" class="ctl-source" onchange="run()">

                                                        <option value=" ">Todos</option>

                                                        @foreach (var item in Model.Select(l => l.Pdv).Distinct())
                                                        {
                                                            <option value="@item">@item</option>
                                                        }

                                                    </select>
                                                    <input type="submit" value="Actualizar" />
                                                }
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row" id="dateWidgetIncomeBanquetPanel">
                            
                                <table class="table table-hover no-more-tables table-iconmebanquet-detail">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="">Platillo</th>
                                            <th style="">PV</th>
                                            <th style="">1</th>
                                            <th style="">2</th>
                                            <th style="">3</th>
                                            <th style="">4</th>
                                            <th style="">5</th>
                                            <th style="">6</th>
                                            <th style="">7</th>
                                            <th style="">8</th>
                                            <th style="">9</th>
                                            <th style="">10</th>
                                            <th style="">11</th>
                                            <th style="">12</th>
                                            <th style="">13</th>
                                            <th style="">14</th>
                                            <th style="">15</th>
                                            <th style="">16</th>
                                            <th style="">17</th>
                                            <th style="">18</th>
                                            <th style="">19</th>
                                            <th style="">20</th>
                                            <th style="">21</th>
                                            <th style="">22</th>
                                            <th style="">23</th>
                                            <th style="">24</th>
                                            <th style="">25</th>
                                            <th style="">26</th>
                                            <th style="">27</th>
                                            <th style="">28</th>

                                            <th>Total</th>
                                            <th>Venta</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                   
                                    <tbody>

                                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                                        {

                                            var total = 0;
                                            decimal costo = 0;

                                            for (int i = 1; i <= 28; i++)
                                            {
                                                var value = 0;
                                                if (item.Fecha.Day == i) { value = item.Cantidad; costo = costo + item.Total; }
                                                total += value;
                                            }
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>@item.Descripcion</td>
                                                <td>@((costo / total).ToString("C"))</td>
                                                @for (int i = 1; i <= 28; i++)
                                                {
                                                    var value = 0;
                                                    int month = item.Fecha.Month;
                                                    if (item.Fecha.Day == i) { value = item.Cantidad; }
                                                    <td>
                                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="popover"
                                                           data-html="true" data-original-title="@i/@month/2015" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Producto: @item.Descripcion<br />PV:@((costo / total).ToString("C"))<br />Total:@value<br />Venta:@(((costo / total) * value).ToString("C"))" data-trigger="hover">@value</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                }
                                                <td>@total</td>
                                                <td>@(((costo / total) * total).ToString("C"))</td>
                                            </tr>

                                        }

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   
                           
</div>
```

what im doing wrong?
Any help wil be apreciated

Comment: You form posts back to Index()`, not `SimpleInterest()`. If you want to post to `SimpleInterest()` then you need to specify the action name in the `BeginForm()` method. And what is the purpose of the javascript `Run()` method?

Comment: i added the run method because i have my selected option to execute run() onchange but wasnt working either, and how can i especify the action in the beginForm()?

Comment: `@using (Html.BeginForm("SimpleInterest", yourControllerName, FormMethod.Post)) { ...`

Comment: Its just `"HomePos"` (not `Arpon.Web.Brain.Pos.Controllers.HomePosController`)

Answer (score 0):

The overload `Html.BeginForm()` will render a form tag with the action attribute value set to the current action method. That means if your executing this code from `Index` action of `HomePos` controller, Razor will generate the following markup

```
<form action="/Home/Index" method="post">   
  <!-- Other form elements-->
</form>
```

Since you want to post it to a different action method, you may try this [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String%29)

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName,  string controllerName
)
```

Update your view code to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SimpleInterest","HomePos"))
{
  <select id="pdvlist" name="pdvlist" class="ctl-source">
      <option value="No">No</option> 
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Actualizar" />
}
```

Now in your code, I don't know what is `onDocExtendedLoad`. But looks like you are trying to execute the run method on the change event. Inside the run method, you are registering a change event handler to the dropdown **everytime**. I am not sure this is something you really want to do. If you are simply trying to get the selected option value when user changes the dropdown, you may use some unobtrusive javascript to do that.

```
@section Scripts
{
  <script>
    $(function(){  
       $('select[name=pdvlist]').change(function (e) {
          var selectedVal = $(this).val();
          alert(selectedVal);
          // If you want to submit the form
          // $(this).closest("form").submit();
       });
    });
</script>
}
```